# Excel formula - Return value from lower row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm looking for a way to search for a value in a single column and return a value in that same column two below it. Example:

- A1: Apples
- A2: Bananas
- A3: Oranges
- A4: Pears

If I search for "Bananas", I'd like to get a return value of "Pears".

Eventually, the number of rows shifted down would be a variable as well, determined by user input (it could be 1 to 3 steps lower than the original value's cell).

Answer (score 1):

You can use INDEX and MATCH with the rows offset by 2 or whatever number you need, e.g. for your example

`=INDEX(A3:A6,MATCH("Bananas",A1:A4,0))`

With a named search range you can do the same with OFFSET, i.e. with Fruit as the named range

=OFFSET(Fruit,MATCH("Bananas",Fruit,0)**+2**-1,0,1)

Where +2 defines the "offset"